# Can I use PEAR to include module in web app?

Tags: php, web-applications, version-control, pear

I am creating a web app in LAMP. It was a while since I last created anything in PHP and back then I wasn't familiar with things like package managing and version control. I'm going to use MySQL in my app so I found the abstraction layer module MDB2 in PEAR.

My previous experiences tell me that I should be able to fetch the module to a `lib/` subdirectory in my development repo, so that it will be present with every clone of the repo. But PEAR installs to `/usr/share/php`.

Can I make PEAR fetch to my development repo?

Or am I taking the wrong approach? My base problem is how to include a PHP module in the app that I'm creating.

Comment: you have to fetch the repo dynamically every time or Once for installation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure PEAR to install into any directory you want, with a custom configuration file:

```
$ pear config-create lib pear.cfg
```

Now you need to tell the pear installer to use the config file:

```
$ pear -c pear.cfg install mdb2
```

That's all.

---

Btw, I recommend to use PDO as database layer if you don't need deep abstraction.

Comment: Thanks. I actually switched to PDO.